# Unable to install RTAI-Lab

Tags: scientific-computing

I hope somebody can help me with a problem that has been driving me crazy.

I am trying to install RTAI-Lab but so far I have not had any success.

The document https://www.rtai.org/RTAILAB/RTAI-Lab-tutorial.pdf describes the installation procedure, inculding how to patch the kernel. However, all I want to do is to install RTAI-Lab so I can generate C-code from scilab models and then include these in a different project. In that way, I am interested in using scilab like Matlab/Simulink to generate code from a simulation model.

I downloaded the tarball of RTAI 3.9 from https://www.rtai.org/ and extracted it into a folder in my home folder.

There seem to be two ways to install RTAI-lab, but neither has worked for me so far.
The extracted tarball has a rtai-lab folder which contains an INSTALL file, giving instruction on how to install RTAI-Lab.
The rtai-lab folder has a subfolder called scilab5, which has a makefile to patch scilab 5.2.1 to make rtai-lab

Which instructions should I follow? I have been trying for some time to get this installed, trying several different installation instructions, and keep running into problems that I cannot solve.

I am using Ubuntu 11.4

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. In the end I solved this problem by installing RTAI-Lab, including the patched kernel. The instructions only seem complicated because they are so long, but I was able to install RTAI-Lab without any significant problems.

The scilab5 subfolder worked for me.